# SQL Server - all possible combinations of Bit columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, combinations, sql-insert

I have an empty table with 7 BIT columns (A, B, C, D, E, F, and G). I am looking to populate this table with rows representing all possible combinations of these columns.  Ideally there would be no rows containing duplicates of the exact same combinations. Although I am showing 7 columns here, the number of columns could be greater, so the solution should be scalable.

A snippet of the table after being populated would look similar to below:

[image]

Ideally this would be based on an INSERT statement, but I am open to a T-SQL Loop solution as well. I have tried using CROSS JOINS, but my limited knowledge has not gotten me very far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a CTE and `CROSS JOIN` it with itself 7 times, as in:

```
with bits as (select 0 as bit union select 1)
select
  row_number() over(
    order by a.bit, b.bit, c.bit, d.bit, e.bit, f.bit, g.bit) as id,
  a.bit, b.bit, c.bit, d.bit, e.bit, f.bit, g.bit
from bits a
cross join bits b
cross join bits c
cross join bits d
cross join bits e
cross join bits f
cross join bits g
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query

```
;with bits as (select * from (values(0),(1)) as bits(d))
select *
from
    bits as b1,
    bits as b2,
    bits as b3,
    bits as b4,
    bits as b5,
    bits as b6,
    bits as b7
```

Comment: This will work, but you should really use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92.

Comment: For something like this, @TheImpaler it's not really needed. Stuff like this (and creating a tally) are about the only times I would say that comma delimited is ok. Especially as a comma delimited list of tables is a `CROSS JOIN` and that is exactly what is wanted (not an implicit `INNER JOIN`). The lack of `CROSS JOIN` on ever line actually makes the statement much more succinct.

Comment: @Larnu I think I'm in a crusade against old joins. I don't know ;)

Comment: I agree, that they should almost never be used, @TheImpaler , but using an old style cross join, to create a cross join and succinct code, isn't a bad thing (in my opinion). ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with recursion.

This solution is less performant than the previous one, I know, because it makes all possible permutations

but at least, it has the advantage that it's scalable on the permutation number

```
declare @mytable as table (s varchar(10))
insert into @mytable values('1'),('0');

with cte as(
select 0 as perm,cast(s as varchar(10)) s from @mytable
union all
select perm+1,cast(t1.s+t2.s as varchar(10)) from cte t1 inner join @mytable t2 on 1=1
where perm <=7)
select * from cte where perm=7 order by s
```