# Creating a sum of each unique combination of 2, 3 or 4 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, apply

This is how my table looks like right now:

```
DECLARE @indicators TABLE([Date_row] date, ind1 int, ind2 int, ind3 int, ind4 int, ind5 int);
INSERT INTO @indicators VALUES
  ('2010-01-01', 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
, ('2011-01-01', 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
, ('2012-01-01', 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
, ('2013-01-01', 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
, ('2014-01-01', 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
, ('2015-01-01', 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)

select * from @indicators

Date_row    ind1    ind2    ind3    ind4    ind5
2010-01-01  1   0   0   0   1
2011-01-01  1   0   0   0   1
2012-01-01  1   1   1   0   1
2013-01-01  1   1   0   1   1
2014-01-01  1   0   1   1   0
2015-01-01  1   0   1   1   0
```

And the outcome I'm looking for is the sum of each unique 2 column combination of ind1, ind2, ind3, ind4, ind5

So basically:

```
SELECT
ind1 + ind2 as ind1_ind2,
ind1 + ind3 as ind1_ind3,
ind1 + ind4 as ind1_ind4,
ind1 + ind5 as ind1_ind5,
ind2 + ind3 as ind2_ind3,
...
```

But for all columns, and preferably the ability to create this combination for however many columns I specify (2,3,4 etc.)

I can visualize how I would create this in python or R but having a hard time seeing how to do this with SQL Server. Something with `cross join`, `pivot`/`unpivot` or `cross apply`. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Be great to see what you have tried.

Comment: If you want to create columns dynamically from the data, then you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: The queries are at https://stackoverflow.com/q/59971453/11683. Generate them dynamically from the column names that you want.

Comment: Please show the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot the data and put the data in *rows* rather than columns:

```
with u as (
      select i.*, v.*
      from indicators i cross apply
           (values ('ind1', ind1), ('ind2', ind2), ('ind3', ind3), ('ind4', ind4), ('ind5', ind5)
           ) v(ind, val)
     )
select u1.ind, u2.ind, sum(u1.val + u2.val)
from u u1 join
     u u2
     on u1.date_row = u2.date_row and u1.ind < u2.ind
group by u1.ind, u2.ind;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4af726f3720fe5dce08f21623a182f54) is a db<>fiddle.

You can easily extend this to more combination by adding more joins in the `from` clause.